# how to avoid open ended versions in transitive dependences of maven project?

Tags: validation, maven, dependencies, version

There are a lot of suggestions avoid using open ended versions of dependences.
And this is really good idea. 
I need to validate several big projects and find if they have any  ranges in versions among all transitive dependencies.
First intention was to use enforcer plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html.
 But it can do such validation only for plugins.
My task looks like very common, but I can’t find any existed solution so far.
Now I am going to write custom rule for enforcer plugin for checking versions unless there is another simple way to achieve my goal.
Any ideas are welcome
thank you

Comment: Version ranges are the enemy of build repeatability... Personally I'd avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned. version ranges make a build unpredictable and not reproducible which is really evil.

Comment: I am totally agree. That's why it looks strange that there is no any ready solution to make sure that version ranges are not used.

Comment: The thing is that in earlier days of Maven many people used it but over the time they learned and avoided versions ranges. But it is possible to use version ranges with Maven. I think if you really need to check this kind you should create an enforcer rule for that.